# how to generate reports for C code with clang

Tags: llvm, clang, static-analysis

Following the directions from the main clang static analyzer web page (http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html)...

I have a small C file that is heinously bug-ridden (`badcode.c`):

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int j;
    int a[4];
    puts(a[j]);
    return 'a';
}
```

In order to get a basic idea how the clang static analyzer (scan-build) words, I run:

`scan-build -v clang badcode.c`

It outputs:

```
scan-build: Emitting reports for this run to '/tmp/scan-build-2012-08-17-1'.
scan-build: 'clang' executable not found in '/usr/share/clang/scan-build/bin'.
scan-build: Using 'clang' from path: /usr/bin/clang
badcode.c:7:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'puts' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        puts(a[j]);
        ^
1 warning generated.
scan-build: Removing directory '/tmp/scan-build-2012-08-17-1' because it contains no reports.
```

Ok, great, clang gives a little warning, but a.out is still produced. And how come it doesn't produce a report? The unititialized variable `j` should be a painfully obvious red flag to any static analyzer -- why isn't it reported?

Am I simply using the wrong command line arguments?

Comment: What version of clang do you use? Clang 3.1 produces correct report with warning "Array subscript is undefined".

Comment: FWIW, the warning is also correctly output by Clang 3.0, and Frama-C Nitrogen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

scan-build -k -V -o scan-reports xcodebuild clean build -configuration Debug -sdk [sdk-version] -xcconfig=[xconfig-certificate-file]

**E.g.:**
scan-build -k -V -o scan-reports xcodebuild clean build -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos5.0 -xcconfig="/Users/username/config.xcconfig"

This should create a html output.